# Skype uri opening skype window but not placing calls

Tags: python-3.x, uri, skype

I am using this function to call a skype user. Once run, it opens the Skype window but no call is being placed. However if I paste the uri in browser, the call gets initiated instantly. One observation is, in browser it asks to open the url to open in Skype and when I click it, it initiates call automatically.

```
    import webbrowser
    number = 'skype.test.user.1'


    # Generate Skype URI for the number
    skype_uri = f"skype:{number}?call"
    
    # Open the Skype URI in the default web browser
    webbrowser.open(skype_uri)
```